# Can Mott insulator conduct electricity?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, strong-correlated

Some people say that when the electrons are excited beyond the Mott gap, the electrons will just hop to the neighbor ions and stop there so will not contribute to electrical conductivity. Is this true?